# Building object models around external data

Tags: python, django

I want to integrate external data into a Django app. Let's say, for example, I want to work with GitHub issues as if they were formulated as normal models within Django. So underneath these objects, I use the GitHub API to retrieve and store data.

In particular, I also want to be able to reference the GitHub issues from models but not the other way around. I.e., I don't intend to modify or extend the external data directly.

The views would use this abstraction to fetch data, but also to follow the references from "normal objects" to properties of the external data. Simple joins would also be nice to have, but clearly there would be limitations.

Are there any examples of how to achieve this in an idiomatic way?

Ideally, this would be would also be split in a general part that describes the API in general, and a descriptive part of the classes similar to how normal ORM classes are described.

Comment: What main benefits are you looking to extract from this? Writing forms? Just fetching data for views? Doing `joins` ?

Comment: @DavidVeza Yes, the views would use this abstraction to fetch data, but also to follow the references from "normal objects" to properties of the external data. Simple joins would also be nice to have, but clearly there would be limitations.

Comment: Can you provide sample data?

Comment: @ElrondSupportsMonica basically any structured data, say JSON, will do as an example. Follwing the example from my question, you could look at https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/

Comment: It sounds like to me you just need to use serializers. Like first build the model based on what the json gives you then serialize the json to fill out that model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The django way in this case would be to write a custom "db" backend.

This [repo](https://github.com/primal100/django_any_backend) looks abandoned but still can lead you to some ideas.

Comment: From the description, this repo looks very promising. Too bad it is so outdated, but I agree this could be a good starting point.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use **Django Model-like** interface for your Github Issues, why don't use real **Django models**? You can, for example, create a method `fetch` in your model, that will load data from the remote api and save it to your model. That way you won't need to make external requests everywhere in your code, but only when you need it. A minimal example will look like these:

```
import requests
from django.db import models

from .exceptions import GithubAPIError


class GithubRepo(models.Model):
    api_url = models.URLField()  # e.g. https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World


class GithubIssue(models.Model):
    issue_id = models.IntegerField()
    repo = models.ForeignKey(GithubRepo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    node_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    body = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    """
    Other fields
    """

    class Meta:
        unique_together = [["issue_id", "repo"]]

    @property
    def url(self):
        return f"{self.repo.api_url}/issues/{self.issue_id}"

    def fetch_data(self):
        response = requests.get(self.url)
        if response.status != 200:
            raise GithubAPIError("Something went wrong")

        data = response.json()

        # populate fields from repsonse
        self.title = data['title']
        self.body = data['body']

    def save(
        self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None, update_fields=None
    ):
        if self.pk is None:  # fetch on first created
            self.fetch_data()
            super(GithubIssue, self).save(
                force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields
            )
```

You can also write a custom [Manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/) for your model that will fetch data every time you call a `create` method - `GithubIssue.objects.create()`

Comment: I simply would prefer having redundant data.

Comment: Nevertheless, thank you a lot for the detailed suggestion. I will keep that in mind as a simple alternative if a custom DB backend doesn't seem to go the right way.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to just use normal OOP principles, Polymorphism, Association etc. to get a similar feel to real models.

But I'm not sure I would try to simulate behavior as close as I could, because the ORM is specifically designed for database interaction. I would just write my custom methods.

Comment: To be honest, I had hoped for a more concrete example. I do have a general Idea how to do it using the normal OOP principles. My issue is particularly on integration with the Django model stack, i.e. enabling interoperability with normal models, reusing code where possible, and preparing for compatibility in newer versions.

Comment: Creating a class that includes the functions for view to retrieve external data, and make a decorator for the model class to inject all the functions needed.